# Is it possible to reattach the v-brake spring/pin arm?

Tags: brakes

I was fitting new brake pads to my (mini) v brakes and stupidly pushed one of the arms very far inward to get easier access.

The spring (actually I'm not sure I mean spring, the pin/spring that pushes the arm back from the rim) either popped out or snapped, I couldn't tell which.

I couldn't really tell where it was meant to reattach or screw back in. Does anyone have a diagram or such showing how it should attach? Or can anyone explain how it should be attached?

I do not believe it's a model with multiple holes for different tension but I could be wrong.

It is completely loose now and the brake arm has no tension.

The brakes are very similar to these [Tektro RX5 brakes](http://tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=55&sortname=Brake&sort=1&fid=2) unfortunately the manual on that page doesn't mention adjusting/refitting the spring.
[image]

Comment: Need a picture of the brake and bike where the brake attaches.

Comment: Possibly not a detailed enough picture but it's the v brakes on here: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/ridley-x-bow-1317a-105-2013-black-54cm/

Comment: The brakes are very similar to these http://www.tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=55&sortname=Brake&sort=1&fid=2 unfortunately the manual on that page doesn't mention adjusting/refitting the spring.

Comment: This type of brake has a pin/spring which is designed to allow the calliper to sit back to the non-braking position. The pin naturally comes away from the brake body as you loosen things up. So if it "popped out" you should be ok. However if it "snapped", that's a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by unhooking the inner cable, like you're about to take the wheel out.

Then unscrew the big silver bolt that goes into the brake boss on the chainstay(rear) or fork(front)

Slide the brake arm off and inspect the spring.  If spring is in more than one piece, you'll need new ones.  Replace both springs to keep the tension close to even.

If everything looks okay, undo the good brake arm *carefully* and inspect how it goes together.  Reassemble the bad one repeatedly till you get it working right.

Don't forget to use blue locktite/thread locker on the two big bolts.

Comment: Yeah, I've never found these brakes to be especially hard to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small pin jutting off the bottom of the v-brake which acts as a spring anchor when inserted into one of the holes in the frame during brake installation assembly. This 2mm pin sheared off on mine during a rough derusting today. I could fashion a repair anchor using a drill/thread tapset and a screw pin but it's not worth the time. I might dream up a makeshift anchor clamp tonight or visit a bike shop to get a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  What does your bike shop have to do with OP fixing a brake?  SE requires any affiliations to be declared, and SE is not a vehicle for advertising.   Please have a browse of our [tour] to see how things work. then ask in [chat] if there are any questions.

Comment: @Criggie Note that one needs [20 reputation to use chat](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I was unaware... It should be lower than that.

Comment: @Criggie I guess it's to keep spammers out. 20 rep is only +2 on an answer or +4 on a question, so it shouldn't be too difficult for a genuine user.